# Bad lag in Android Studio Visual Layout Editor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

In the latest version of Android Studio, I'm getting really bad lag when adding constraints in the Visual Layout editor when using a ConstraintLayout. It freezes for a second or two when I first click the handle to add a constraint.

I've got 12GB of Memory (out of a total of 32GB) allocated to AS, AS running on an SSD, i7 Processor running at 4.0GHz, so I know it's not my system.

Any ideas? Anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 2):

I am currently exploring same issues on Android Studio 3.0 Preview 2. 
Especially when waking PC up from sleep mode and reusing Android Studio.

It starts lagging more when I have android studio and visual layout designer opened for a long time.

So, I restart Android Studio when it starts lagging or delete caches and restart and waiting for a new version of android studio.

You may apply more ram for java. Propably this is going to help a bit.